# How to disable Resharper auto format on save in VS2015

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

How to disable Resharper auto format on save in VS2015?

I have uncheck the auto format option but its not working.

[image]

Comment: I assume you've tried disabling ReSharper to check that it is doing the auto formatting? Are you running the latest version of ReSharper? Is it the same on all projects, even a new one? What language(s) are you using? You could try resetting your ReSharper settings.

Comment: Also, check that there are no 3rd party plugins installed into Visual Studio, which can force ReSharper formatting to run like the "ReSharper Format On Save" plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MackenzieZastrow.ReSharperFormatOnSave